# Apply android:excludeFromRecents for all activities in application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-task, android-recents

Is there a way to set `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to all activities in application instead of specifying for each activity?

Comment: no, there is no such way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **No.** You can not use `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in application tag. You have to use this property for each activity seperately. For more go to this link and see different properties only in `<activity>` tag.
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exclude